# GL_QUADS method having weird outputs

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Okay so this thing I've been working on has this class, Construct.

```
package od.methods;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;


public class Construct {
    public static void box(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glVertex2i(x,y); //Top Left
            GL11.glVertex2i(x+width,y); //Top Right
            GL11.glVertex2i(x+width,y+height); //Bottom Right
            GL11.glVertex2i(x,y-height); //Bottom Left
        GL11.glEnd();


    }
}
```

So you'd think that would construct a box. It doesn't the only time it shows something is if you have the values set to

```
box(0, 0, width, height);
```

And when yo do that, no matter the width or height it makes the block a quarter of the screen. If for X and Y you do any value other than 0, nothing comes up.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: This coordinates don't make a rectangle. The last line has a `-height` instead of `+ height`.

Comment: @BDL I'm sorry, I must not understand what you're saying. I thought that I was trying to get it under the x,y, and doing so would be y-height . Wouldn't y+height get it above x,y?

Comment: You have coordinates on three different y-coordinates at the moment: y, y+height and y-height. That's definitely not a box. Try to draw the vertices you have on a sheet of paper and see what happens: The result is not a rectangle but two triangles and thus a concave figure. OpenGL can only draw convex quadrilaterals.

Comment: @BDL see now. That did fix orientation, however I still am unable to give any x or y values other than 0

Comment: Do you use any projection? Otherwise the visible area ranges from [-1 to 1] on each axis.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I feel really dumb right now. I should've known to put this little bit of init code

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, -1, 1);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```